# Can I get IP address and port of disconnected client in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

Currently when my tornado server receives a 'connection opened' event, I store the client's WebSocketHandler in a `players` dict with its key being and IP/port combo.

```
players = {}

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        global players
        players[self.get_id()] = self

    def get_id(self):
        ip = self.request.remote_ip
        port = str(self.stream.socket.getpeername()[1])
        return ip + ":" + port
```

What I'd like to do is remove the player from the `dict` when its connection closes. Something similar to this:

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def on_close(self):
        global players
        players.pop(self.get_id(), None)
```

The port doesn't seem to be accessible so I can't re-create the id that I had set up previously. Is it possible to retrieve the port some other way?

Comment: Store the id as an instance attribute…? `self.id = self.get_id()`. Then it's available later on. (I _believe_ Tornado creates a new `WSHandler` instance for each connection, so this should do.)

Comment: Perfect, don't know why I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each connection will create its own instance of `WSHandler`, so simply store the data on the instance on initialisation:

```
def open(self):
    self.id = self.get_id()
    ...
```